# Let $G=\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ be additive and $H=\{0\}\times\Bbb Z$. Show that: a) $H\le G$. b) $H\cong \Bbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-isomorphism, direct-product

I did more or less the item

a)
$H$ is a subset of $G$ so we need to show that $H$ is a group.

$H$ is associative because

$$\begin{align}
[(a, b) + (c, d)] + (e, f) &= (a + c, b + d) + (e, f) \\
&= (a + c + e, b + d + f) \\
&= (a, b) + [(c + e, d + f)] \\
&= (a, b) + [(c, d) + (e, f)].
\end{align}$$

$H$ has a neutral element because
$$(0,0) + (a, b) = (a, b)$$

Does $H$ have an inverse? (Not because $H$ is of the form $(0, x)$ where $x\in\Bbb Z$
$$(-a, -b) + (a, b) = (0.0)$$

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: $(0, -x)$ is the inverse of $(0, x)$, and any such element belongs to $H$ by definition. For b), try constructing an isomorphism directly (say, $f(0, x) = x$).

Comment: Please use MathJax. [Here’s a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Right now, what you write is almost unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a)

I will use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test).

Since $(0,0)\in H$, we have $H\neq \varnothing$.

By definition of $H$, we have $H\subseteq G$.

Let $x,y\in H$. Then $x=(0,a), y=(0,b)$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb Z$. Now

$$\begin{align}
x-y&=(0,a)-(0,b)\\
&=(0,a)+(0,-b)\\
&=(0,a-b).
\end{align}$$

But $a-b\in\Bbb Z$, so $x-y\in H$.

Hence $H\le G$.

---

For b), consider

$$\begin{align}
\varphi: H&\to \Bbb Z\\
(0,h)&\mapsto h.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$H $ is a subset and a group  (easy).  $\varphi:\Bbb Z\to\{0\}\times\Bbb Z $ by $x\mapsto (0,x) $ is an isomorphism.